# Limited blog post showing up on main page and label search

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have a blog - http://mecoffeyjourney.blogspot.com/ which currently has about 8 posts.

The issue is at my main page, there are only 4 posts showing up (4 of the latest posts), even when I set the limits to 30 posts in the settings.

Same goes when I display by labels. For example one of the labels should be tied to 6 posts, and when I arranged by labels, only 4 posts shows up (4 of the latest posts).

Is there any issue with the blog template? Appreciate anyone's help on this.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that most of my posts are too large in size (lots of pictures in every posts), and the limit of a blog's main page is only 1 MB. Thus in the end blogger automatically limits the large posts to only 4 posts in the front page (or even label search).

To rectify this issue, the key here is to use the 'Page Break' function (a useful page which I refer to http://buzz.blogger.com/2009/09/you-might-as-well-jump.html)

The key is to limit the details of each posts that the main page will capture so that it does not reach the 1 MB limit. I change all my blog post to have a 'Page Break' after only one picture and a short description (for my main page to display the single picture as a thumbnail for each post and a short description).

After changing all blog posts, my main page can now display more than 20 posts.

Comment: Is that what you have been looking for?